# Facebook Send button automate destinations

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I've tried to insert the Facebook Send Button HTML code but I'd like to set destination users/groups automatically by javascript.
Is it possible?

**I have to click on a Send Button and this is what I should see:**

> DESTINATION: Friend1, Friend2, .....

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'send',
        link: 'http://www.google.it',
        id:  [XXXXXXXXXXXX],
        message: 'Arrived?'
});
```

XXXXXXXXX = Facebook APP User ID

with "Friend1..." set automatically

I've tried with **to** but it shows nothing 
Thanks!

Comment: You can specify _one_ target user via the `to` parameter, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog#params

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I've found that but when I fill that attribute with the App User ID of a friend, I obtain nothing more than before.